# The thermodynamics associated with conditional probability?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, measurements

So I'm quite confused by an answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510626/150174

> Let $|\psi\rangle$ be the initial state, and let $U_t=e^{-i Ht}$ be
>   the evolution operator, assuming a time-independent Hamiltonian. I
>   will also assume for simplicity that we are working on a discrete
>   basis. If you want to work with continuous variables, you can replace
>   sums with integrals and you should mostly be fine.
>
> Suppose we start at $t=0$, and measure the state at times
>   $\{t_k\}_{k=1}^N$, letting it evolve freely in the intermediate times.
>
> Measuring at $t=t_1$ gives the outcome $x$ with probability
>   $p(x,t_1)=|\langle x|U_{t_1}|\psi\rangle|^2$, and a post-measurement
>   state $|x\rangle$. Write the coefficients of $|\psi\rangle$ in the
>   basis of $|x\rangle$ as $|\psi\rangle=\sum_x c_x |x\rangle$, and
>   define the kernel of the evolution as $K(x,y;\delta t)\equiv\langle x|U_{\delta t}|y\rangle$.
>
> Finally, let us define $\Delta_k\equiv t_k- t_{k-1}$. We can then
>   write $p(x,t_1)$ (assuming a discrete set of possible outcomes) as
>
> $$p(x,t_1)=\left|\sum_y K(x,y;\Delta_1)c_y\right|^2.$$
>
> Because we don't know the post-measurement state after the first
>   measurement, we now need to switch to a density matrix formalism to
>   take into account this classical uncertainty. We therefore write the
>   post-measurement state as :
>
> $$\rho_1=\sum_x p(x,t_1) \mathbb P_x,
> \text{ where } \mathbb P_x\equiv |x\rangle\!\langle x|.$$
>
> At time $t_2$, before the second measurement, the state is therefore
>   given by
>
> $$\tilde\rho_2=\sum_x p(x,t_1)\, U_{\Delta_2}\mathbb P_x U_{\Delta_2}^\dagger,$$
>
> which then results in an outcome $x$ with probability $p(x,t_2)=\sum_y |K(x,y;\Delta_2)|^2 p(y,t_1)$, and a post-measurement
>   state
>
> $$\rho_2=\sum_{x}p(x,t_2) \,\mathbb P_x
> = \sum_{x,y} |K(x,y;\Delta_2)|^2
> \Big|\sum_z K(y,z; \Delta_1)c_z\Big|^2 \, \mathbb P_x.$$
>
> You can keep going and compute the state at each successive
>   measurement time $t_k$. If this reminds you of Feynman's path integral
>   formulation, it's because it kind of is. The difference is that here
>   you break the interference at every measurement time, and so the final
>   state is determined by a mixture of quantum interference and classical
>   probabilities.
>
> Define now for ease of notation $q_k\equiv p(x,t_k)$. What is the probability of finding at specific $x$ for the first
>   time at the $k$-th measurement? This will equal the probability of
>   *not* finding it in the previous measurements and finding it at the $k$-th, that is,
>
> $$(1-q_1)(1-q_2)\cdots (1-q_{k-1})q_k.$$
>
> Note that with this formalism you can also answer other questions
>   about the probability of finding a given result once or more at
>   specific combinations of times. For example, the probability of
>   measuring $x$ *at least once* will be given by
>
> $$1-\prod_{k=1}^N (1-q_k).$$
>   I don't know if there is a nice way to write these expressions in
>   general. Maybe, if you write probabilities back in terms of the
>   kernels, but I haven't tried, and the post already got a bit too long.

I mean it starts of with nice pure states which have $0$ entropy and it then starts to use density matrices with mixed states which have non-zero entropy.

### Question

Is there some kind of $2$'nd law of thermodynamics here too then about the measurement of time through this? And what is the temperature and heat associated here? I was thinking using the Shanon entropy definition would help this cause?

Comment: Density matrices are just the most general states in quantum mechanics. They have no more to do with thermodynamics than a general probability distribution does. Shannon/von-Neumann entropy $\neq$ thermodynamic entropy. But if you want to find connections between time measurements and thermodynamics, you can have a look at one of [our papers, here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06704).

Comment: @MarkMitchison This is so funny I was working on something that has made me ask a whole load of questions. One of my friends even prompted me to read precisely that paper. And here I am talking to the author of that very paper :P

Comment: @MarkMitchison an on topic question would then be is can't I calculate the entropy of the density matrix as non-zero when it's a mixed state?

Comment: The von Neumann entropy of a mixed state is non-zero, by the definition of a mixed state. Is that your question?

Comment: @MarkMitchison I guess it boils down to how to show there is (or isn't) a 2' nd law or heat or temperature in the context I'm talking about?

Comment: @MarkMitchison Also this whole debate of is information entropy = thermodynamic entropy is part of a broader debate which I haven't seen done in this context:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263197/150174